# .NET Group Policy\Machine folder

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, group-policy

I have a unique requirement (let's just leave it at that) to access the System32\GroupPolicy\Machine folder from C#.  I can browse to the directory with full control, but when accessing from C# I get the following error:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\windows\system32\grouppolicy\Machine'.

I can't use any other traditional methods of accessing policies, it has to be done through the file system.  Here's the code I'm using just trying to browse the directory:

```
  string[] files;
```

`files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\grouppolicy\Machine");`

Running Visual Studio as admin, Win 7 64 bit

**EDIT**

Directory.GetDirectories(Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\grouppolicy\") also returns no folders even though I see 3 subfolders in explorer.

Comment: This folder `Machine` is user-created? or system's?

Comment: It's created by the OS I believe on install.  It's on all my VM's by default.

Comment: Well, I don't have that one. Let me double check. EDIT: Nop. Yeah, i did that.

Comment: It's hidden, you may have to un-hide system folders to see it.

Comment: Have you tried to change your app manifest?

Comment: You mean this:   <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly being redirected to the syswow64 directory due to 32 bit application on 64 bit OS.  (just wasted 3 hours beating my head on the desk same issue).  Per MSDN use SYSNATIVE instead of SYSTEM32.

Like:

```
    string[] files;
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSNATIVE\\GROUPPOLICY\\MACHINE");
    }
    else
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\GROUPPOLICY\\MACHINE");
    }
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
```